# PHP matching all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using a wordpress plugin called Movie Poster which grabs a movie's info from imdb and displays it in a post. How do I grab just the first Production Co before the first comma? I'm confused on how this code works. Here's the code which grabs all the production co:

```
$arr['productions'] = array();
foreach($this->match('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ms', 
           $this->match('/Production Co.?:(.*?)(<\/div>|See more)/ms', $html, 1)
        , 1) as $m)
    array_push($arr['productions'], $m);`
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: you shouldn't be parsing html with regexes. that's why we have http://php.net/dom

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: @user2336811: Contact the developer of that plugin, tell him about your issue and negotiate a fix.

Comment: I've been trying for weeks but no response :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want **one** Production Co's info?

Why not just get rid of the foreach? You currently have a loop going through and looking for all Production Co. and returning.

Or you could change it to a [While statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) and add a counter so that it only passes through once.

```
$arr['productions'] = array();
$i = 0;
while($i < 1) {
   $m = $this->match('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ms', 
       $this->match('/Production Co.?:(.*?)(<\/div>|See more)/ms', $html, 1)
    , 1);
   array_push($arr['productions'], $m);
   $i++;
}
```

Not sure if the syntax is exactly correct, but should get you in the right direction. Keep in mind, I'm not familiar with the plugin or if I've understood exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS"

Comment: I'm getting "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" in this line of code: `function match($regex, $str, $i = 0){
        if(preg_match($regex, $str, $match) == 1)
            return $match[$i];
        else
            return false;
    }`

Comment: Cool, I didnt get any errors but the post only displays a comma.

Comment: In your original code snippet, you have a ` at the end of the `;`. Is that needed? Wasn't sure if that was just a typo, etc.

Comment: I have this code in another php file, maybe it's comflicting: 
`$TMPL['production'] = '';
    foreach(explode(', ', $TMPL['productions']) as $v)
    $TMPL['production'] .= $v.', ';`

Comment: The problem may be that we're not assigning `$m` anywhere. Try changing it to `$m = $this->match`...

Comment: Nice. Glad to be of help. Go ahead and accept the answer. I've edited my post so that it shows the complete answer.